# Laplace transform of a squared function

Tags: laplace-transform, nonlinear-analysis

The Laplace transform often comes in handy for solving linear ODEs. But, linear ODEs are often approximations of nonlinear ODEs that have less trivial solutions.

Given $f(t)$ and that its laplace transform exists, is there a closed formula for the laplace transform of $f(t)^2,$ and more generally,$ f(t)^n?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Laplace transform of $f(t)^2$ is $(F\star F)(s)$ where $\star$ denotes convolution. Similarly, the Laplace transform of $f(t)^n$ is given by $(\underbrace{F\star \ldots\star F}_{n\ \mathrm{ times}})(s)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you happen to have any references to support your formula? For instance, some convolutions are of infinite bounds, some are of finite bounds, I don't know which one you're proposing.

Comment: Check the basic rules of the Laplace transforms.  They can be found in any textbook, wikipedia, etc .